# characters in Matrix column

Tags: r

Can any one suggest how to remove quotes around all numbers, and around "C" and "?".

```r
library(QCA)
cbind(createMatrix(c(2,2,2)), c("?", 1, 1, "?", "C", 0, 0, "?"))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "?" 
#> [2,] "0"  "0"  "1"  "1" 
#> [3,] "0"  "1"  "0"  "1" 
#> [4,] "0"  "1"  "1"  "?" 
#> [5,] "1"  "0"  "0"  "C" 
#> [6,] "1"  "0"  "1"  "0" 
#> [7,] "1"  "1"  "0"  "0" 
#> [8,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "?"
```

Comment: character elements have quotes.  Not clear about your requirement.  May be convert to `data.frame` and it will print without quotes

Comment: i..e. `transform(as.data.frame(createMatrix(c(2,2,2))), V4 = c("?", 1, 1, "?", "C", 0, 0, "?"))`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `noquote()`

```
library(QCA)
dm <- cbind(createMatrix(c(2,2,2)), c("?", 1, 1, "?", "C", 0, 0, "?"))
dm <- noquote(dm)
dm
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0    0    0    ?   
[2,] 0    0    1    1   
[3,] 0    1    0    1   
[4,] 0    1    1    ?   
[5,] 1    0    0    C   
[6,] 1    0    1    0   
[7,] 1    1    0    0   
[8,] 1    1    1    ?
```